# Get current year in MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you get the current year (as a four digit number) for use in a MySql `WHERE` clause?

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblfeatured WHERE yeargrad LIKE date('Y')
```

The `yeargrad` columns stores just a year (e.g  2017) and I would like to find rows where this matches the current year.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `curdate()` function to get today's date and then use `year()` function on it to get the current year.

```
SELECT * FROM tblfeatured WHERE yeargrad = year(curdate());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tblfeatured WHERE YEAR(yeargrad) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: `yeargrad` is mentioned as just storing the year, and not being a DateTime. It isn't clear from the question if this is a VARCHAR or an INT.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sake, please note you can also use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y')
```

or

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y')
```